# Difference between TextToSpeech.addEarcon() and TextToSpeech.addSpeech()

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I just started working on Android's `TextToSpeech` API and I came accros two methods which seem to be exactly the same namely:

> **[TextToSpeech.addEarcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#addEarcon(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) :**
> Adds a mapping between a string of text and a sound resource in a package. Use this to add custom earcons.

and

> **[TextToSpeech.addSpeech()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#addSpeech(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) :**
> Adds a mapping between a string of text and a sound resource in a package. After a call to this method, subsequent calls to speak(java.lang.CharSequence, int, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.String) will play the specified sound resource if it is available, or synthesize the text it is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while writing the question I did a bit more research and turns out an Earcon is a term going back to 1985:

> A brief, distinctive sound that represents a specific event or conveys other information. Earcons are a common feature of computer operating systems and applications, ranging from a simple beep to indicate an error, to the customizable sound schemes of modern operating systems that indicate startup, shutdown, and other events - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earcon)

Never would've guessed Earcon as a word/term.